# How to use "google_service_account_access_token" scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to set-up my terraform's `main.tf` by using service accounts that get impersonated by authorized users... I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-gcp-service-account-impersonation-in-terraform-af98853ebd37) to set this up, and it works, I can create a bucket within my project and within my organization.

Now in order to do more specific stuff, like declare these blocks

```
data "google_organization" "org" {
  organization = var.organization.id
}
data "google_billing_account" "acct" {
  billing_account = var.billing_account.id
  open            = var.billing_account.active
}
```

I figured (but I may be wrong) that I need to include more elements in the scope of my provider, like this :

```
provider "google" {
  alias = "super_admin_impersonation"
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit",  # I added this
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-billing"  # And this
  ]
}
```

and so, also add them to the `google_service_account_access_token` block

```
data "google_service_account_access_token" "super_admin" {
  provider               = google.super_admin_impersonation
  target_service_account = "${var.service_acc_terraform_super_admin.name}@${var.project_infra_genesis.id}.${var.service_acc_terraform_super_admin.suffix}"
  scopes                 = ["cloud-platform", "userinfo-email", "admin.directory.orgunit", "cloud-billing"]
  lifetime               = "1200s"
}
```

The problem, is that when I add `"admin.directory.orgunit", "cloud-billing"` to this block's scope, I get this error :

```
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
│
│   with data.google_service_account_access_token.super_admin,
│   on main.tf line 22, in data "google_service_account_access_token" "super_admin":
│   22: data "google_service_account_access_token" "super_admin" {
│
╵
```

[Google's official Oauth2 scopes for their APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) is where I determine the names of scopes...

My question is: how do you know which scopes can be used in `google_service_account_access_token`? Is there a complete list I can refer to in order to include more in this block?

Comment: Not an expert in Roles/SA. When you are creating SA token, you have add those roles I guess(You may try those). If you are looking for list of scopes then you can look @ https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles